# How to dynamically change template in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I have a common abstract component that renders tree.

I need to able change template for this component dynamically by condition?

I think tree logic should be in separeted service. And I have to create two components with different templates, that use tree service, is not?

Lets assume, I have tree of country/cities.

On one page I need to show that in DOM structure:

```
<div class="root">
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="children"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In another page I need to show the same DOM but with some  differences.

```
  <div class="root">
        <div class="parent">
           <div class="children"><label></label><input></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, certainly I can use one template and use `*ngIf` to determine which DOM element show/hide.

But I need to separate templates and load them dinamically.

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. Can you add some code please?

Comment: Sure, just a moment, check out again please

Comment: Perfect, I believe you can solve it very easily using `<ng-template>`: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Comment: Your example look to me like it would be simple to just use *ngIf, like you already mentioned. Does your case get substantionally more difficult? If you add the same things at multiple points, you should put that in a `ng-template`:   "<label></label><input>" in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show template based on variable. To choose template use `*ngIf`. Let me show an example:

HTML of shared component:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showWithoutLabel; else showWithLabel">
    <div class="root">
        <div class="parent">
           <div class="children"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #showWithLabel>
    <div class="root">
        <div class="parent">
           <div class="children"><label></label><input></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

TypeScript:

```
showWithoutLabel = false;
```

Comment: Similar think I did previously, tree structure data I populate recursively in typescript and depend on scenario I can render front end. So html rendering part is dump terminal and it will render data from typescript.